# how to capture the value from request body in vugen?

Tags: loadrunner, dynamic-values

```
web_submit_data("LoadRunner_Correlation_Challenge_Exp.aspx_4", 
        "Action=http://loadrunnertips.com/LoadRunner_Correlation_Challenge_Exp.aspx", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=http://loadrunnertips.com/LoadRunner_Correlation_Challenge_Exp.aspx", 
        "Snapshot=t27.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=__EVENTTARGET", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=__EVENTARGUMENT", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=__VIEWSTATE", "Value={VIEWSTATE}", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "Value={VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION", "Value={EVENTVALIDATION2}", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=ctl00$head$txtMagicNo", "Value=1118330860", ENDITEM, //1118330860
        "Name=ctl00$head$btnStep2", "Value=Next", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);
```

this is LoadRunner challenge expert level as I was trying this  I encountered the above call where the value 1118330860 appears in the request body of this call only and not on any above calls and any subsequent calls how can I capture this value as I have to pass this in same call. How can I capture the value and use it in this call?

Thank you,
Nayan

I tried correlating it as a regular correlation and it did not work and i tried sending the dummy request before this one hoping that i would get that value in response got errors instead

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner_Correlation_Challenge_Exp

We will not do your pre-employment screen for you

Comment: http://loadrunnertips.com/LoadRunner_Correlation_Challenge_Exp.aspx